# Where to find Win32 constants?

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi

I have been doing some com interop stuff in c# lately to try and control buttons, comboboxes, textboxes, etc. on another application.  My question is related to the Win32 constants some people would post, example:

```
const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Where do I find the WM_SETTEXT constant ?  I have looked up certian functions on MSDN but they don't always explicitly say what the constant value is.  For example, looking for the CBN_SELCHANGE constant on MSDN gives this page [CBN_SELCHANGED MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775821(VS.85).aspx).  So, where is the best place to get this information?

Comment: For C, on my machine, I can go to c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1a\Include, and look at winuser.h to see what WM_SETTEXT is supposed to be.  The version number for you may be different (mine is v7.1a).

Comment: You can find them in [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants.WM#)

Comment: @InBetween There are many missing constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PInvoke.net is nice website which demonstrates the usage of User32 external dlls. You can find the related documentation as well.

Try this website http://pinvoke.net/

Comment: Nice, thanks for pointing out that PInvoke.net contained that information. I was able to find the following pages which summarized exactly what I was looking for. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html

Comment: @Joseph - Please accept my comment as answer as it has helped you with what you were looking for. - Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1. C++ MSDN.
   `#define WM_SETTEXT                      0x000C`
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
2. In a header.
   Look at the  `Header` section onto MSDN page (Winuser.h (include Windows.h))

Comment: Install the [SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive), grep the headers.

Comment: Or better: use MSVS IDE (SDK will be installed with IDE) to find definition instead grep.

Comment: Sure, if you want to be fancy.  :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) to look up the various constants and imports. For example, the page for `WM_SETTEXT` [is here](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=WM_SETTEXT&namespace=[All])

Comment: Nice, thanks for pointing out that PInvoke.net contained that information. I was able to find the following pages which summarized exactly what I was looking for. pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html –